# How to disable mouseover event from everywhere using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, mouseover

I am using raphael.js library and this file contains a mouseover event which I want to stop working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295221/how-to-disable-mouseover-event-with-javascript-jquery

did you look at this?

Comment: yea, but it did not workout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use CSS:

```
.element {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or something like:

```
$('.element').on('mouseover mouseenter mouseleave mouseup mousedown', function() {
   return false
});
```

I don't know from what you want to prevent that event from triggering something, please be more specific on your questions and provide more relevant information.

Comment: Is there any possibility to stop the mouseover event present in a particular js file as i have 4 js files and it is blocking of all the files. I want to block mouseover event only of a single file i.e. raphael.js

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could simply create an overlay which will catch events and prevent bubbling using `event.stopPropagation()`.

As `mouseover` and `mouseout` events do not bubble from child to parent element, it becomes even easier - creating an invisible overlay is enough.

Without overlay:

```js
$("p").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).text("Gotcha!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Mouse over me</p>
```

With overlay:

```js
$("p").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).text("Gotcha!");
});
```

```css
#mouseoverDisabler {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15); /* just for demo. make it 0.0 */
z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mouseoverDisabler"></div>

<p>Mouse over me</p>
```

The background color is red on purpose - it will help you to understand the idea. You can set it to transparent and will not be visible.